# How to get image source from a website - Swift & Kanna

Tags: swift, html-parsing

I am currently trying to parse an image link from a [website](http://www.gunnoracle.com) using Kanna and Swift.

However, when I try using the doc.css or doc.xcpath, it does not work. I have used doc.css to parse the titles and dates, however, I am not sure as to how I can parse the image source. Also if possible, I would like it if you could include in your answer a way to use the image link in my UIImageView(linked by IBOutlet).

Below is the code I have tried and also a snippet of the inspect element feature of the website itself.

```
func parseHTML(html: String) -> Void {
        if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {

            for link in doc.xpath(".//div[@class='loop-thumb'/a[1]/img[1]]") {

                print(link.text)//where I am trying to get the image source
                self.imageURLs.append(link.text)//array of all image links
            }

        }
        self.postTableView.reloadData()//my tableview name
    }
```

[image: inspect element of website]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to finding the source of an image and using it to place it in my view controller.

```
func parseHTML(html: String) -> Void {
        if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {

            for item in doc.xpath("//div[@class='loop-thumb']/a") {//goes through the xpath and looks at the directories for each one that matches

                let imageURL = (item.at_xpath("img")?["src"])//gets the image source

                if(imageURL! == "https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/themes/premium/mh-magazine/images/noimage_174x131.png"){ //checks if no image, and replaces with The Oracle placeholder image
                    self.imageURLs.append("https://scontent.fsnc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12002228_10153530981476668_4060049645901806384_n.jpg?oh=daf19a8eaf94db01fddd0516e25146f8&oe=5A4F5E34")//appends placeholder image for each article with no image
                }
                else {
                    self.imageURLs.append(imageURL!)//appends the image URL to the array of image urls
                }
            }


        }
```